# Using sed with special characters

Tags: sed

I have a directory full of XML files that look like this, for which I want to change the value of the "offset" element number from 1 to some other number

```
$ cat my.xml
      <offset xmlns="">1</offset>
```

I wrote various combinations of this sed command, but nothing I tried runs without an error.  I am pretty sure that I need to escape some of the characters, but those that I've tried always end in errors ("unexpected token", "unknown option", etc).  I also tried without the -e flag, since it really isn't an expression.

```
sed -i -e s/<offset xmlns="">1</offset>/<offset xmlns="">99</offset>/ *.xml
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
$ sed 's~<offset xmlns="">1~<offset xmlns="">99~g' file
          <offset xmlns="">99</offset>
```

Use a different sed delimiter if the input contain slashes.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to use `/` in sed, you can use comma for example:

```
sed -i 's,<offset xmlns="">1</offset>,NEW_TEXT,' FILE
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't usually need all of that in the `s/earch/replace/` function itself, and can instead first `/address/` then conditionally `/s///`. It can not only help with readablity and to avoid some of the issues you mention, there can be a performance increase as well:

```
sed '/offset xmlns=/s/>1</>99</'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper parser for XML files. For example, I'd use [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2) and use the following script:

```
for my $file in { @ARGV } {
    open $file ;
    for //offset set . 1 ;
    save :b ;
}
```

Comment: Probably the most proper answer, but I don't have that installed on this host.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the 17th character of the line, which contains the value:

```
sed -i 's/^\(.\{17\}\)./\1VALUE/' file.xml
```

Replace VALUE with the new value for `<offset>`. Eg.

```
sed -i 's/^\(.\{17\}\)./\18/' file.xml
```

to change it to 8.